# File Extension query in Oracle/Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a table tblAttachmentDetails which contains ID,FileName & LastUpdated.

```
ID    FileName     LastUpdated
 1    Abc.txt      12/12/2011
 2    dsa.doc      12/12/2008
 3    ddd.xls      12/12/2003
 4    Accbc.xlsx   12/12/2006
 5    cc.txt       12/12/2006
 6    cc.doc       12/12/2006
 7    cc.xls       12/12/2008
 8    cc.xlsx      12/12/2012
```

I want top 10 rows of .xls & .xlsx files order by LastUpdated.

Oracle :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAttachmentDetails 
where ROWNUM <= 10 
and FileName Like '%.xls%' 
order by LastUpdated Desc
```

Please correct me in this query, because from this query i m only getting  .xls files not xlsx.

Comment: Did you forget the quotes around '%.xls%'?

Comment: I think answer is much important then quotes. :)

Comment: Please read the manual to understand how to work properly with the rownum pseudo-column: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#i1006297

Answer (score 2):

The `ROWNUM` filtering should be applied after the filtering by type and ordering..

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT *
           FROM tblAttachmentDetails
           WHERE FileName Like '%.xls%'
           ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC
       )
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

Comment: But this will return only the top 10 .xls files and i need both .xls & .xlsx files

Comment: It will return both `.xls` and `.xlsx`. Are you sure you are not dealing with a case sensitivity issue i.e., `WHERE LOWER(FileName) LIKE '%.xls%'` OR your first `.xlsx` file is older than the first 10 `.xls` files.

Comment: @intelliWork: so you want 20 rows in total?